# MySQL insert multiple rows with function with while loop

Tags: mysql, database, function, while-loop

I'm trying to insert multiple rows in a MySQL database. First, I create insert function for address, which connects to another table that only contains the formatted address, so I make inserts for it in another function.

Then in a third function I'm trying to populate a third table with first generating dummy addresses for it. For some reason even the first lower level function (address_insert()) fails to execute due to SQL syntax error and I cannot figure out what it could be. Any ideas?

Thanks!
First function:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS address_insert;
CREATE PROCEDURE address_insert()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address) + 1;
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

WHILE (counter < 5) DO 
INSERT INTO hoop.address (adr_id, address, city, country, created_at, lat, lng, updated_at, zip)
VALUES                   (i, CONCAT("Address-", i), "City", "United States", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, RAND(35, 50), RAND(80, 120), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "ZIPCODE");

    SET i = i + 1;
    SET counter = counter + 1; 
END WHILE;
END;
```

Second function:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS address_shop_insert;
CREATE PROCEDURE address_shop_insert()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address_shop) + 1;
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

WHILE (counter <= SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address) DO 
INSERT INTO hoop.address_shop_insert (formatted_address, adr_id)
VALUES                               ("Formatted Address", i);

SET i = i + 1;
SET counter = counter + 1; 
END WHILE;
END;
```

Final function:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS merchant_shop_insert;
CREATE PROCEDURE merchant_shop_insert()
BEGIN
address_insert()
address_shop_insert()

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.merchant_shop) + 1; 
DECLARE merchant_accounts INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.merchant_account) + 1;
DECLARE shop_address_id DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address_shop) - 5;
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE account_mod INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE account_id INT DEFAULT 1;

WHILE (i < merchant_accounts) DO
 IF 
    SELECT MOD(account_mod, 5) = 0
    SET account_id = account_id + 1;
 END IF;

 IF counter = 5
    SET shop_address_id = shop_address_id + 1;
    SET counter = 1;
 END IF;

  INSERT INTO hoop.merchant_shop (shop_id, contact_name, contact_phone, created_at, shop_name, status, updated_at, acc_id, shop_adr_id) 
  VALUES (i, "Strawberry Peach", "+361/789-6544", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONCAT("Shop", i), 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, account_id, shop_address_id)

  SET i = i + 1;
  SET account_mod = account_mod + 1;
  SET counter = counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the semi-column `;` ends a command, you need to define a specific one for the stored procedure creation, otherwise, MySQL won't know what is the delimiter that tells the end of the declaration of the procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS address_insert;    

-- Set the delimiter to $$
DELIMITER $$

-- Notice that every instructions IN the procedure will be ended by the regular delimiter ;
CREATE PROCEDURE address_insert()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address) + 1;
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    WHILE (counter < 5) DO 
        INSERT INTO hoop.address (adr_id, address, city, country, created_at, lat, lng, updated_at, zip)
        VALUES                   (i, CONCAT("Address-", i), "City", "United States", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, RAND(35, 50), RAND(80, 120), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "ZIPCODE");

        SET i = i + 1;
        SET counter = counter + 1; 
    END WHILE;
-- vv------------------------ Notice this
END$$

-- Set it back to ;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't solve the syntax error though.